# source multiple files in .zshrc with wildcard

Tags: macos, terminal, alias, zsh

I use z shell via "oh my zsh". I'd like to source multiple alias files from within my .zshrc file so I can keep things well organized. I've prefixed the alias files with `.alias_` so I can wildcard load them. But, a call to `source ~/.alias_*` only loads the first file. How can I script it to source multiple files?

Filename examples:  `.alias_git`, `.alias_local`, `.alias_server`...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Option 1

You could use a for loop:

```
for file in ~/.alias_*; do
    source "$file"
done
```

### Option 2

The other option is to build an array of all the files you want to source and then iterate over the array using a for loop.

```
typeset -a aliases

aliases+="~/.alias_foo"
aliases+="~/.aliases_bar"
# etc...

for file in $aliases[@]; do
    if [[ -a "$file" ]]; then
        source "$file"
    fi
done
```

This can actually be quite effective in making [a well organized zshrc setup](https://github.com/seebi/zshrc/blob/master/zshrc).

Comment: Why is typeset -ga used instead of typeset -a? Why do we need it to be global?

Comment: It doesn't need the `-g` flag. Updated answer.

Comment: what about `source $(ls /foo/*/bla)`? seems to work in an interactive shell but not in the .zshrc...

Comment: Have a look at this answer too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480771/419658

Answer (score 4):

An even more ZSH-specific way (requires `setopt EXTENDED_GLOB`):

```
alias_src=(
.alias_git
.alias_local
.alias_server
)
for f ($^alias_src(.N)) source $f
unset alias_src
```

The prefix `^` has the effect of applying the subsequent glob modifiers to every element of the array separately.

The trailing `(.N)` has the following effect:

- `.`: only match files
- `N`: temporarily `setopt NULL_GLOB`, which means that only those elements of the array that actually exist remain in the array