# How do I debug where files break in a sourceing of files via wild card in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc

I have a line in my .zshrc file, `source $SNIPPETS/*.zsh` and I know it's partially working because some functions defined in the directory work, but others do not unless I specifically source the file exclusively.

What steps would I take to find where in the sourcing there is an early exit or break?

Answer (score 1):

You can only `source` one file at a time. The first file is being sourced, but not the rest.

You'll need to use a loop in `.zshrc`

```
for i in "$SNIPPETS"/*.zsh; do
    [[ -e "$i" ]] && source "$i"
done
```

Comment: TODAY I LEARNED!

Answer (score 1):

TODAY I LEARNED: that `source` only works on explicitly called files. One can input multiple files but no wild cards.

None of my files were breaking.

Steps I took for debugging:

1. Started a new shell.
2. Enabled `zprof`. (`zmodload zsh/zprof`)
3. Ran the source line. `source $SNIPPETS/*.zsh`
4. Realized that only one file was being sourced.
5. Re scoped my search for 'zsh source wildcard`
6. Found and implemented option one from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14680403/5724147).

Comment: Actually, you *can* use several parameters with `source`; it is just that the remaining arguments turn into positional parameters. Hence, if the first file in the list is the one which is actually being sourced, the second one is assigned to parameter $1, the third one to parameter $2 and so on. Read _man zshbuiltins_, which explains this.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks, I updated my answer based on that!